# Do size ability score changes apply as temp or perm?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores

I am working on updating my character spreadsheets, and while redesigning the sheet for ability scores I am confused as to where the size changes should apply.

Now if your race was naturally large+/tiny- then clearly its perm. When taking into consideration both wildshape and enlarge/reduce it becomes less clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All [bonuses to your ability scores](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/glossary.html#ability-score-bonuses) are temporary until they've lasted more than 24 hours, regardless of where they come from.

> **Permanent Bonuses**: Ability bonuses with a duration greater than 1 day actually increase the relevant ability score after 24 hours. Modify all skills and statistics related to that ability. This might cause you to gain skill points, hit points, and other bonuses. These bonuses should be noted separately in case they are removed.

If an effect lapses and is reapplied, such as with wildshape or spells with a shorter duration, that does not count for the "duration greater than 1 day" requirement. Even overlapping durations will not get you around that.

If your race is naturally a size other than Medium, the changes to your ability scores are included in the adjustments or stat block already. For example, [a Trox](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary4/trox.html#trox) increases their Strength by 6 after buying/rolling their ability scores, they do not have a +6 size bonus to Strength. An ogre has a Strength of 21, not a +10 size bonus to Strength. If one of these were to cast *[beast shape II](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/beastShape.html#beast-shape-ii)* to become a Large animal, they would still gain a +4 size bonus to Strength. This would **not** result in the Trox's Strength decreasing.

Comment: What happens when it replaces a perm such as naturally being larger or smaller then?

Comment: "Ability bonuses with a duration greater than 1 day actually increase the relevant ability score after 24 hours."  That's a weird way of phrasing it.  Does that mean that after a day, the change happens in another day, i.e. it actually takes two days?  I don't think that's the intent, but that's one interpretation of the awkward wording.

Comment: @SouthpawHare I think it's supposed to be read as "24 hours after the start of an effect that grants an ability bonus for at least one day, the bonus is treated as a permanent increase until the effect ends".

Comment: @Fering what do you mean?

Comment: @Fering If your natural size isn't Medium, the size adjustments to your ability scores are baked in. You don't have bonuses at that point, any more than you have racial bonuses. Those exist solely when creating your character.

Comment: Using the race builder, its possible to be large. This gives you some ability score changes which are type size, the same as enlarge/reduce person. Oddly enough they dont stack, but fully replace each other. Since the racial size bonus is perm, and the spell is temp, I was simply trying to figure out how to arrange things in my new spreadsheet.